# Using value from database as a link - using ejs in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I want to get a value from database and assign that value to the 'href' attribute of anchor tag.I am using node js ,mongodb,ejs.
I tried :

```
 <a href="<%=link%>"><%=link%></a>

   res.render("form.ejs",{link:item.shortUrl});
```

'item.shortUrl' contains the link fetched from database.
When I run this, it says- " 'link' is not defined".How can i make this work?Please help..
Thank You!

Comment: Are you sure that item.shortUrl is will be a valid link? So your db query is ok?

Comment: Try removing `.ejs` from your  `res.render("form.ejs",{link:item.shortUrl});` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below things and correct your code accordingly.

**Set your default views directory and view engine:** (If not done already)

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

**Remove `.ejs` from your `res.render..` statement:**

```
res.render("form",{link:item.shortUrl});
```

**Always have a conditional statement to check the existence of the variable that you are trying to output:**

```
<% if (link) { %>
    <a href="<%=link%>"><%=link%></a>
<% } %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I tried the above changes but still getting the same error.Thank You.

Comment: Can you try hardcoding your `link` variable like, `res.render('form',{link:'http://www.google.com'});` and see if it works?

Comment: I am sorry. Thats not working either.same error.Thank You.